# how to change desktop windows application icon for flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I used the desktop flutter and I searched for a way to do that I couldn't find any articles about that, so I want to know how to change the launcher app icon for Windows desktop and also for Mac and Linux.

[UPDATE]
Now [flutter_launcher_icons package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) supports all platforms

To set it up:

1. Create a file and may name it as flutter_launcher_icons.yaml
2. Add configuration to flutter_launcher_icons.yaml
3. Specify image paths and platforms

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "path/to/image.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"
  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: "path/to/image.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "path/to/image.png"
```

4. Run pub get and the package

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons -f flutter_launcher_icons.yaml
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To change the icon you just need to replace the icon file in your project:

- Windows: windows/runner/resources/app_icon.ico
- macOS: macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

Linux doesn't have an icon set up in the template yet; you can follow [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53229) for updates.

Comment: i made an ico file with my logo and replaced it with the ico file at `resources/app_icon.ico` but it did not change the icon

Comment: `flutter build windows` doesn't pick up `windows/runner/resources/app_icon.ico` for the release version. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any way we could change the app icon in the runtime?

Comment: To anyone stumbling upon this issue: at first, it seems that replacing `app_icon.ico` won't do anything. I tried several other methods, including specifying another file in `Runner.rc` as mentioned below, but nothing seemed to work. In the end, I invalidated caches for Android Studio, rebooted my PC, run a `flutter clean` then rebuilt my app. In the end, the icon got updated by replacing `app_icon.ico`.

Comment: @il_boga You should file a bug; if it requires a `clean` that's something that should be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

To change the icon in windows you have to keep the icon file in this location:

> windows/runner/resources/

Then go into windows/runner/resources/Runner.rc file and search for the word **app_icon**. You will reach here:

```
IDI_APP_ICON            ICON                    "resources\\app_icon.ico"
```

Replace the **app_icon** with your icon file name. Then run the command

```
flutter build windows
flutter run --release -d windows
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Linux**

Best And Simple way is to use   `gtk_window_set_icon_from_file` function

Edit Your `my_application.cc` file which is inside Linux folder  `linux/my_application.cc`

- before  line `gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(window));`
- add new line `gtk_window_set_icon_from_file(GTK_WINDOW(window),"assets/icon.ico",NULL);`
- Icon recommends 48x48 pixel

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: please show me your code

Comment: I added the line `gtk_window_set_icon_from_file(GTK_WINDOW(window),"images-icons/out/icons/win/icon.ico",NULL);` and there is no change in the linux executable appearance either. Does the icon need to be in `assets/` and registered as an asset using `pubspec.yaml` perhaps?

Comment: Actually before I made the above code change, the default app icon was still the same generic grey gear symbol that I'm getting now - not even the classic flutter icon. So if the flutter team can't change the icon then what hope do we have!

Comment: Turns out that the gtk call above needs the icon file to be present at runtime, e.g. in the directory (or subdir) of the deployed executable. You will see a warning in the terminal when running if the icon file you specify cannot be found. So in the end I got the icon loading OK. However the icon of the deployed executable is still generic, and the icon as displayed in the Ubuntu dock at runtime remains generic - so there is no visible useful effect of this line of code, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I hava the best way, using **Flutter Launcher Icons** for your Windows, Android etc.

1. Edit your *pubspec.yaml* file:

> dev_dependencies:
> flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.10.0"
>
> ```
> flutter_icons:
>   android: "launcher_icon"
>   ios: true
>   image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
>   min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
>   web:
>     generate: true
>     image_path: "path/to/image.png"
>     background_color: "#hexcode"
>     theme_color: "#hexcode"
>   windows:
>     generate: true
>     image_path: "path/to/image.png"
>     icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
> ```

2. Go to Terminal, run:

> ```
> flutter pub get
> flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
> ```

Note:
**Name of your icon is lowercase, don't use capital.**

Answer (score 1):

After trying all of these steps for weeks, what really worked for me was to change the app description on those fields on `Runner.rc`:

- FileDescription
- InternalName
- OriginalFilename
- ProductName

I also changed the BINARY_NAME description field on `CMakeLists.txt`.

After changing the description for some reason, the icon is updated. I didn't tried, but you can try to switch your app name back to the previous one after you successfully update the launcher app icon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my setup from `flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale en-CA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.10.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Initially it didn't work by just replacing the icon and run

```sh
flutter build windows
```

and neither did

```sh
flutter clean
flutter build windows
```

I found that in the running mode the icon updates on the GUI, but unfortunately not in the EXE itself.

```sh
flutter run --release -d windows
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and worked for me 100%

dev_dependencies:
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

flutter_launcher_icons:
android: "launcher_icon"
ios: true
image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
web:
generate: true
image_path: "path/to/image.png"
background_color: "#hexcode"
theme_color: "#hexcode"
windows:
generate: true
image_path: "path/to/image.png"
icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
macos:
generate: true
image_path: "path/to/image.png"
Run pub get and the package

at the end run these in terminal
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons -f flutter_launcher_icons.yaml