# How to change app icon and app name for Flutter Desktop application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm using Flutter to develop Windows desktop application, but don't know how to change the name and icon for the application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change desktop windows application icon for flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558578/how-to-change-desktop-windows-application-icon-for-flutter)

Answer (score 25):

I think I've found the solution. The following should work for Windows application:

To change application icon:
Simply put icon file under `windows/runner/resources` folder, and change the `IDI_APP_ICON` part in `windows\runner\Runner.rc` file to your icon file name.

To change application name: Open `windows/runner/main.cpp` file, and change your application name inside `window.CreateAndShow` function.

Comment: You've described changing the window title, but your question is about the application name. What exactly is it that you wanted to change?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to change the filename of the icon instead of just replacing the existing icon file?

Comment: how to change name of the exe in flutterapp\build\windows\runner\Release?

Comment: To change the build name. Please navigate to Windows/CMakeLists.txt and update set(BINARY_NAME "ANYNAME").

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to change the icon and the name of a **Windows app**.

### App icon

Just replace the file `app_icon.ico` in `windows/runner/resources` with your new icon.

If the name has changed, rename `app_icon.ico` with your new filename in the file `windows\runner\Runner.rc` :

```
// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_APP_ICON            ICON                    "resources\\app_icon.ico"
```

### App name

It gets a bit more complicated. There is no such thing as an "app name" in Windows. You can change the name of the window, the name of the output executable file, the name displayed in your Task Manager ...

Let's say the name of your project was `oldbadname`. You should replace `oldbadname` with `yournewname` and `Old Bad Name` with `Your New Name` in all the following files :

**windows/runner/Runner.rc**

```
BEGIN
    VALUE "CompanyName", "com.company" "\0"
    VALUE "FileDescription", "Old Bad Name" "\0"
    VALUE "FileVersion", VERSION_AS_STRING "\0"
    VALUE "InternalName", "Old Bad Name" "\0"
    VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2023 com.company. All rights reserved." "\0"
    VALUE "OriginalFilename", "oldbadname.exe" "\0"
    VALUE "ProductName", "Old Bad Name" "\0"
    VALUE "ProductVersion", VERSION_AS_STRING "\0"
END
```

---

**windows/CMakeLists.txt** (and not windows/runner/CMakeLists.txt)

```
set(BINARY_NAME "foldername")
```

---

**windows/runner/main.cpp**

```
if (!window.Create(L"Old Bad Name", origin, size)) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

That's it !

Comment: don't change set(BINARY_NAME "oldbadname") it will cause cmake error. the binary name should the same as the project folder name

Comment: Yes changing this doesn't work, but the comment in the code says you can change it:
`# The name of the executable created for the application. Change this to change
# the on-disk name of your application.
set(BINARY_NAME "app_name")`
Either the comment is wrong or you also need to change something else for this to work.

Comment: I also had to do a `flutter clean` after those changes in order to get it building again.

Comment: change `set(BINARY_NAME "oldbadname") `  will cause cmake error.
`flutter clean` fix that error

Comment: Should I remove the line `set(BINARY_NAME "foldername")` for `windows/CMakeLists.txt` ?

Answer (score 4):

add this in your void main()

```
void main() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS) {
    setWindowTitle('title here');
  }
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Include this dependency in pubspec.yaml for this to work:

```
window_size:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
      path: plugins/window_size
      ref: 7812516a5c1fc8ef379e244106953a2b534432b9
```

Answer (score 2):

To change your Flutter project name for Windows, follow these simple steps:

Open the following file in your project: `windows/runner/Runner.rc`

```
BEGIN
VALUE "CompanyName", "com.example" "\0"
VALUE "FileDescription", "NameApp" "\0"
VALUE "FileVersion", VERSION_AS_STRING "\0"
VALUE "InternalName", "NameApp" "\0"
VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2023 com.example. All rights 
reserved." "\0"
VALUE "OriginalFilename", "NameApp.exe" "\0"
VALUE "ProductName", "NameApp" "\0"
VALUE "ProductVersion", VERSION_AS_STRING "\0"
END
```

Replace all occurrences of NameApp with your new desired name, let's say NewNameApp.

Open the following file in your project: `windows/runner/main.cpp`

```
if (!window.CreateAndShow(L"NameApp", origin, size)) {
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Replace "NameApp" with "NewNameApp".

Save the changes, close the files, and run your app again.

Answer (score -2):

**Change App Icon:**

Best and easy way to use this package - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

How to configure & more details refer this - [Flutter app cannot be uploaded to Microsoft Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555437/flutter-app-cannot-be-uploaded-to-microsoft-store)

**Change App Name**: You can modify app name in this file -

```
windows/runner/Runner.rc
```

Comment: does this show how to change the app name?

Comment: Change App Name: You can modify app name in this file -windows/runner/Runner.rc