# Flutter app cannot be uploaded to Microsoft Store

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, microsoft-store

I've asked this before but I'm still lost. I'm trying to upload my Flutter app to Microsoft Store but I keep getting '10.1.1.11 Inaccurate Representation - Icon' detail on certification report.

This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  beautiful_soup_dart: ^0.3.0
  http: ^0.13.5
  html: ^0.15.0
  chaleno: ^0.0.6
  provider: ^6.0.0
  accordion: ^2.5.1
  simple_circular_progress_bar: ^1.0.2
  window_size:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding
      path: plugins/window_size
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  msix: ^3.13.2

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  image_path: "assets/logo/logoIcon.png"
  windows: true
```

I don't know what to do anymore. Support sends me the icon (flutter logo) but they don't tell me where does it appear or where in the code it is triggered. I looked for the icon inside the project but I couldn't find anything like that, all the images in it are original.

On my first post, someone told me to change the 'flutter_launcher_icons' configuration but it did not change anything either.

Comment: can you share the error message which you get from Microsoft?

Comment: @ForStack "10.1.1.11 Inaccurate Representation - Icon" -
The available product tile icons include a default image. Tile icons must uniquely represent product so users associate icons with the appropriate products and do not confuse one product for another. For information about tiles see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets, or for 3D icons for Mixed Reality products, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/3d-app-launcher-design-guidance.  - 
Tested devices: Microsoft Surface Laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I've finally done it**

After a lot of changes in my pubspec.yaml I think the main problem was that some attributes were missing in my msix configuration. Just in case it does not work for you after changing the config, this is how my .yaml looks like right now:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  beautiful_soup_dart: ^0.3.0
  http: ^0.13.5
  html: ^0.15.0
  chaleno: ^0.0.6
  provider: ^6.0.0
  accordion: ^2.5.1
  simple_circular_progress_bar: ^1.0.2
  window_size:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding
      path: plugins/window_size

msix_config:
  display_name: (display_name)
  publisher_display_name: (publisher_display_name)
  identity_name: (identity_name)
  msix_version: 1.0.11.0
  publisher: (publisher)
  store: true
  logo_path: (logo_path) # WARNING THIS PATH IS FROM YOUR DISK, NOT FROM PROJECT, READ MSIX DOC FOR MORE INFO
  trim_logo: false

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  msix: ^3.13.2


flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "ic_launcher"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/logo/logoIcon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21

  windows: 
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/logo/app_icon.ico"
    icon_size: 48
```

I hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

As per example code for flutter_launcher_icons you need to specify and provide values to certain params (generate, image_path, icon_size) while generating for Windows, Mac & Web

```
flutter_launcher_icons:
  #  image_path: "assets/images/icon-128x128.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/images/icon-710x599-android.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/images/icon-1024x1024.png"
  android: true # can specify file name here e.g. "ic_launcher"
  ios: true # can specify file name here e.g. "My-Launcher-Icon"
  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/images/christmas-background.png" # only available for Android 8.0 devices and above
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/images/icon-foreground-432x432.png" # only available for Android 8.0 devices and above
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  background_color_ios: "#ffffff"
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon-1024x1024.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"
  windows: //**TODO: Make these changes** 
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon-1024x1024.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon-1024x1024.png"
```

Once you make these changes, run the command for generating launcher icons

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this dependency in `dev_dependencies` not in `dependencies`

Like in this image.
Also check the guide. [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

[image]

Comment: Just uploaded a package, I'll let you know when they send me the report. Thanks, friend!

Comment: Have you updated these changes?

Comment: Yes, right as you showed me earlier.

Comment: I hope it will work.

Comment: Hello again @Ashvin , it seems like writing the dependency on dev_dependencies did not change anything, Microsoft keeps saying the same thing on the report...

Comment: Ohh, what's now?

Comment: @Ashvin I'm guessing that **maybe** the real problem is the msix configuration. I realized that I didn't write the "logo_path" attribute, so I wrote it and sent it to the store, hope it was the problem all this time... I'll keep you guys updated when I get the report.

Comment: @Beni ok, thank you! Please post solution with details if you get success

Comment: @Ashvin good news friend, they accepted my app! I'll edit the main question with the answer. I hope it works for you too!

Comment: @Beni that's great news! Let me try

Comment: @Beni it's fixed for me as well! Thanks friend.