# How to set Release App icon for Flutter Desktop Windows app

Tags: flutter, dart, desktop

I have successfully set the App icon for the debug mode `windows/runner/resources/app_icon.ico` its working fine but when i run `flutter build windows` the `exe` file in the `windows/build/runner/Release` folder it comes with the flutter icon what should i do to build a release with custom icon

i just run `flutter build windows` to make my release

this is my app in debug mode its showing my custom icon

[image]

this is my app in release mode its not showing my custom icon

[image]

Comment: Have you tried these steps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558578/how-to-change-desktop-windows-application-icon-for-flutter

Comment: i clearly said its working fine in debug mode meaning the icon is set to my custom icon but the exe icon comes with the flutter logo

Comment: What steps did you already take to set the debug logo?

Comment: i changed the `windows/runner/resources/app_icon.ico` to my custom icon

Comment: I have the exact same problem, debug builds have the correct icons, but release builds do not. Clearing cache did not help.
Also, in task manager both the icon and the name are incorrect, again only in the release build, in debug all is as expected

Comment: do flutter clean and restart pc

Answer (score 0):

You can use package - **https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons**

For configure & more details refer this -
[Flutter app cannot be uploaded to Microsoft Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555437/flutter-app-cannot-be-uploaded-to-microsoft-store)