# Flutter Window application icon not showing correctly

Tags: windows, flutter, software-design

The icon of exe file generated from building flutter project shows a different icon from the chosen one.

I'm trying to change my desktop app icon without any success. I have already followed the instruction given here [how to change desktop windows application icon for flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558578/how-to-change-desktop-windows-application-icon-for-flutter) and I had success at my first attempt. The real problem is that now the icon of my application is not right when I build it. I don't know how to describe it so I'm going to post some screenshot to let you see the issue.
[This is an example of my current correct icon for the app which shows also both on appbar and as icon on the window when the app is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOGjE.png)
[This is one of the case in which the icon is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYm9y.png)
Funny thing is that the file associated with the wrong icon was deleted some time ago.

Update: After building an installer (using InnoSetup) for the application and install it the icon of the app is shown without the issue described before.

Comment: Refer this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555437/flutter-app-cannot-be-uploaded-to-microsoft-store

Answer (score 0):

try flutter clean or flutter run --release -d windows