# How do I set icon to flutter desktop linux app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-linux

I've a flutter desktop linux app and I want to set icon app so when I build the app by typing this command `flutter build linux` the executable file got this icon and this icon appears at the taskbar.

At this moment the executable file has set a generic icon and when the app is running then the taskbar shows an empty icon.

[image]

I've read the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/73134323/9301998 but this only shows the icon on the taskbar if I run the app typing the command `flutter run -d linux` but when I build the app by typing this command `flutter build linux` it's not assign the icon that I want.

The image that I want to set as icon I've added as assets in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Then I've created a `my_app.desktop` file with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=my_app
Exec=/home/pepe/my_app/build/linux/x64/release/bundle/my_app
Icon=/home/pepe/my_app/build/linux/x64/release/bundle/data/flutter_assets/assets/images/logo.ico
Comment=Welcome to the flutterverse!
Categories=Development;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true;
```

Then I can see the icon on the desktop,  I still add the app as favorite to the taskbar, but when I click on the icon to run the app it runs but it continues adding an empty icon in the taskbar.

This article explains [How to change icon of linux desktop app](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/100/how-to-change-app-icon-widows-macos-linux-flutter-desktop/#how-to-change-icon-of-linus-desktop-app) but it's through snapstore and I would like to do this when I build the app by typing this command `flutter build linux` directly.