# How to set icon to Flutter portable executable application in Linux?

Tags: linux, flutter, icons

We have a Flutter application that we are going to distribute archive as a portable application for Linux.
After building the project, we have an executable file with a system icon. And we need to set the right icon for our executable file.

I tried this article [How do I set icon to flutter desktop linux app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76345434/how-do-i-set-icon-to-flutter-desktop-linux-app), but it did not help.
I tried to use flutter_launcher_icons package, but not worked for Linux.

How can to make it that the end user can immediately see the correct icon after unpacking the archive?